# Use of Hyper Visor to run the Windows Phone Emulator

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-emulator

I am really new to Windows Phone 8 App development. I would be grateful to you if you can answer my question. I have a machine with Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 processor and when checked I found out that my virtualization setting enabled. 
I installed Windows Pro 8.1 in to my machine and then it indicates that my Hyper Visor is default switched off and I had to run it. But when I run it after making some of the changes by restarting the machine, suddenly for some unknown reason it undoes every change made finally leaving the machine with no Hyper Visor running.
I come across the same process when I am to run the Windows Phone emulator to test Windows Phone 8 Apps.
I hope my issue is clear to you all, can someone help me to fix this issue or tell me the exact reason behind this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Usage of Hyper Visor when running Windows Phone Apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27317034/usage-of-hyper-visor-when-running-windows-phone-apps)

Comment: share the folder C:\windows\logs\CBS. here I can see why Windows rolls back the changes

Answer (score 0):

I would look at my Windows Event log and see if you perhaps there's a problem with Hyper-V being incompatible with a driver or something like that.  It may be failing to reboot and the doing a system restore to get the machine back to a bootable state (by rolling back Hyper-V).  I've had problems with Hyper-V and my HP laptop's blue tooth drivers:

Here's the thread where I found out about that:

[HP Bluetooth / Hyper-V woes](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Desktop-Lockups-Freezes-Hangs/Cannot-boot-if-HP-ENVY-Bios-Virtualization-enabled-for-Win8/m-p/2538189#M22348)

Updating the driver to the newest version on HP's site fixed my computer for a while, but then I had problems with Windows Update hosing my machine with an update to the Bluetooth driver.

I seem to have fixed it for good by going to RA Link's website and downloading a version of the driver that's newer than the one on HP's website.  I'm not at my personal computer right now, but if you'd like I can see if I can find the driver version that seems to have fixed my Bluetooth/hyper-v problems for good.

-Eric